# Efficiency, Performance, and Effectiveness of Image Sharpening in Spatial and Frequency domain

Tags: matlab, image-processing, spatial, frequency-domain

My question has 2 parts,

First part, is there a MATLAB function that generates a frequnecy domain mask that sharpens the edges of an image? Or do I have to create the mask in the spatial domain using `fspecial()` and then map it to the frequency domain using `fft2(spatail_domain_mask)`?

Second part,consider an image enhancement technique that sharpens the edges of an image. If we are to compare this operation in the spatial domain and the frequency domain, which one is more effective? Which one is more efficient? And which one has a better overall performance?

Comment: Define "effective".  And define "efficient" vs. "overall better performance".

Comment: effective means it provides a better sharpened output image (highlights the edges more),efficiency: in terms of time and memory, and performance can include different performance metrics including response time, throughput, utilization...etc. Actually, performance and efficiency are correlated here.

Comment: Ok, well every time-domain filter has an exact equivalent in the frequency domain (numerical precision notwithstanding).  So effectiveness is not an issue here.

Comment: for efficiency, it mainly depends on the size of your kernel... convolution with a 3x3 kernel is fast, but if you use a 100x100 kernel, you should rather do it in the frequency domain.

Comment: thanks a lot, what about the first part of the question?